# Dereference a link's "href" as a DOM element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, href

```
  $("#my-tab-link").on("show", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.href);
  });
```

This gives the link's `href` as a string:

```
file:///...index.html?#mytab
```

How do you access the DOM element that the link is pointing to, rather than just its URL?

I can kludge around it like this:

```
$(".known-parent-of-target").find($(e.target).attr("href"))[0]
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Hmm, HTML5 or other doctype?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute("href"))`?

Comment: is `#my-tab-link` the id for the anchor?

Comment: HTML5.  Kolink, that doesn't quite work due to the prepended #. wirey:  it's the id for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `$($(e.target).attr("href"))[0]` or without jQuery `document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute("href").substr(1))`

Comment: Great - I like your first solution the best. Kind of sneaky, in that the href syntax ("#link") exactly matches jQuery ID selector syntax ("#id") - but maybe that's a fundamental design decision.

Comment: @SteveBennett: A design decision that might have come from CSS more than jQuery :) `id`s haven’t been around as long as `name`s.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most elegant way, but it should work. If you already know it's a link, you can do a loop (or each) through all the < a >s and find the one that has the url you want and change it there...

```
$.each($(a), function(i){
  if(e.target.href == $($(a)[i]).attr("href"){
    alert("holy bananas, this is the link you want!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to locate an `<a>` element for the current page's hash e.g. #**mytab**

```
$('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]')
```

Or from string/href attrib

```
var url ="file:///...index.html?#mytab";
var idx = url.indexOf("#");
var hash = idx != -1 ? url.substring(idx+1) : "";
$('a[href="'+hash +'"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it a little cleaner with `getElementById`:

```
var element = document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute("href").substr(1));
```